# Cosmos Graph DB returns sortedranges ArgumentException on some specific nodes

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

When executing a gremlin query like

```
g.V(['partitionKey', 'id']).outE('navigateTo').inV()
```

on some nodes I get an error like

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: sortedRanges
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.IRoutingMapProviderExtensions.<TryGetOverlappingRangesAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
```

I do not know how to solve this, tried al kinds of constructs but did not help

Comment: Can you provide an e2e example of this so we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: Same for me, some queries like 
g.V(['partitionkey', 'id']).repeat(__.in('navigateTo')).times(30).emit().path().by('url') give the same error. Other nodes just return the requested values. I think it has something to do with the related partitionkey / id in the out or in relation